# The nature of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=n/a}^{n}\frac{1}{i} = \ln a$ relation.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

Actually there is a simple formula $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=n/a}^{n}\frac{1}{i} = \ln a$$
But not sure if I understand what is the nature of this relation. This is true for all $a>0$.
Just wanted to point this interesting formula as it shows another face of the natural logarithm.
Let me also say that $a$ can be any irational number.
The question I have is this, how does this work for non integer numbers?
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=n/a}^{n}\frac{1}{i}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\big(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i} - \sum_{i=1}^{n/a}\frac{1}{i}\big)$$ As the $n/a$ will have very similar values for many $a$ numbers because of ceiling.

Comment: You should probably use flooring or ceiling in the sum bounds when dividing.

Comment: Actually the $n/a$ means $floor(n/a)$. And this is the most wondering part.

Comment: Personally, I adopt the notation $\sum_{i=m}^n f(i)=\sum_{\{x\in\Bbb Z\,:\, m\le x\le n\}} f(x)$, and therefore I would say that $\sum_{k=\lfloor n/a\rfloor}^n \frac1k=0$ for almost all $a<1$ (and, for all $a<1$, eventually as $n\to\infty$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say $\sum\limits_{i=n/a}^{n}\frac{1}{i}$ you have to deal with the issue when $n$ is not a multiple of $a$.  You have said in comments you want to take the floor.

Gae. S. has raised the point of $0 < a < 1$ in which case $\lfloor n/a\rfloor$ is   $n$ when $n < \frac{a}{1-a}$, but when $n$ is larger then $\lfloor n/a\rfloor > n$  leaving you with an empty sum of $0$.

Otherwise you have in general $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i} = \log_e(n) +\gamma + O(\frac1n)$

so $\sum\limits_{i=\lfloor n/a\rfloor}^{n}\frac{1}{i} = \log_e(n) -\log_e(\lfloor n/a\rfloor-1)+O(\frac1n) = \log_e(n) -\log_e( n/a)+O(\frac1n)$  since $\frac{1}{\lfloor n/a\rfloor}$ is $O(\frac1n)$ and this means $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum\limits_{i=\lfloor n/a\rfloor}^{n}\frac{1}{i} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left(\log_e(n) -\log_e( n/a)+ O(\tfrac1n)\right) = \log_e( a)$$

when $a \ge 1$, and $0$ when $0 < a < 1$

Comment: Actually the issue I see here is that $\log_e(n/a)$ is not the same as $\log_e\lfloor n/a\rfloor$

Comment: No it is not, but the difference is less than $\frac{2}{\lfloor n/a\rfloor}$ which is $O(\frac1n)$